# How to change the font size in php?

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, font-size

I'm trying to change the font size of the price including tax, not just the suffix 'incl. btw'. Is it possible to do that?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'bbloomer_add_price_suffix_price_inc_tax', 99, 4 );
       
function bbloomer_add_price_suffix_price_inc_tax( $suffix, $product, $price, $qty ){
    $suffix = ' excl. btw <br> ' . wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ) . ' incl.btw';
    return $suffix;
}
```

Comment: Create a CSS class, surround the text you want to change with a `<span>` with that class

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use a span to control the font attributes. Like this

```php
function bbloomer_add_price_suffix_price_inc_tax( $suffix, $product, $price, $qty ){
    $suffix = ' excl. btw <br> ' . 
              '<span style="font-size: large">'.
              wc_price( wc_get_price_including_tax( $product ) ) . ' incl.btw'.
              '</span>';
    return $suffix;
}
```

The code above is formatted for clarity.  It shows the font as **large**, but you can use pixels or other units.  That font size (or other attributes are only in-force within the span.